# Weird pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

What would cause a pointer to look like this in c++? I'm building a Huffman Tree for a project and my program is segfaulting when this is one of the child nodes of the current node. This doesn't get detected by `childNode == NULL` either.

```
(TreeNode *) 0x3130303030313131
```

Edit, the below functions are being called in the following order: `buildTree() -> generateCodes()`

```
void HuffTree::buildTree(MinHeap * heap) {
    while (heap->getSize() > 1) {
        TreeNode * n1 = heap->removeMin();
        TreeNode * n2 = heap->removeMin();

        TreeNode * p = new TreeNode(0, (n1 != NULL ? n1->getFrequency() : 0) + (n2 != NULL ? n2->getFrequency() : 0));
    p->join(n1, n2);

        heap->insert(p);
    }

    root = heap->removeMin();
}

void HuffTree::generateCodesRecursive(TreeNode * node, int right, string code) {
    if (node == NULL) return;

    if (node->isLeafNode()) {
        codes[node->getVal()] = code;
        cout << (unsigned int) node->getVal() << " " << (int) node->getFrequency() << " " << code << endl;
    }

    generateCodesRecursive(node->getLeft(), 0, code + "1");
    generateCodesRecursive(node->getRight(), 0, code + "0");
}

void HuffTree::generateCodes() {
    generateCodesRecursive(root, 0, "");
}
```

Edit, heap functions:

```
void MinHeap::insert(TreeNode * val) {
    nodes.push_back(val);   

    int index = nodes.size() -1 ;
    while (nodes[parent(index)]->getFrequency() > nodes[index]->getFrequency()){
        swapNodes(index, parent(index));    
        index = parent(index);
    }
}

TreeNode * MinHeap::removeMin() {
    if (nodes.size() == 0) return NULL;

    TreeNode* minNode = nodes[0];

    if (nodes.size() > 0){
        TreeNode* lastNode = nodes[nodes.size()-1];
        nodes.pop_back();
        nodes[0] = lastNode;
    }

    int index = 0;
    while((left(index) < nodes.size() && nodes[left(index)]->getFrequency() < nodes[index]->getFrequency()) ||
    (right(index) < nodes.size() && nodes[right(index)]->getFrequency() < nodes[index]->getFrequency())) {
        int swapIndex = right(index) >= nodes.size() ? left(index) : (nodes[left(index)]->getFrequency() <= nodes[right(index)]->getFrequency() ? left(index) : right(index));

        swapNodes(swapIndex, index);
        index = swapIndex;
    }

    return minNode;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't set it to null?

Comment: This is a char array (string) "10000111", not a pointer.

Comment: @Matt may be on the right track, please provide more code

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I added context code

Comment: Where do you create your nodes? Do you set their pointers to null when you create them?

Comment: @Galik Nodes are inserted into the heap using `heap->insert(new TreeNode(c, frequency_table[i]));` where `c` is a char and `frequency_table` is an array of integers.  I will add heap functions to my question

Comment: Another possible point to consider, from personal experience - an invalid value in a function parameter might be caused by an actual stack overflow - insertion of more bytes then originally declared on a variable on the heap, which will overflow on the stack and corrupt data along the way.

Comment: Does the `TreeNode` constructor set its internal pointers to null?

Comment: @Galik The `TreeNode` constructor sets both left child and right child pointers to `NULL`

Comment: Just about any bug anywhere in the code could cause that. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to keep in mind.  When you do `TreeNode* p;` `p` won't be null and will point to garbage memory, which won't be detected by `if (p == NULL)` or `if (p == nullptr)` conditions unless you explicitly set it to `null` during initialization.

Also, are you initializing the internal data member of TreeNode in it's constructor properly?

Answer (score 1):

You would get such an invalid pointer value if you have some data that is not a pointer and you try to pretend it's a pointer.

The most likely way you would obtain such a pointer is from an uninitialized pointer variable. In C and C++, uninitialized variables - including pointers - may contain unpredictable "random garbage" values.